SharePoint Online PowerShell - Publish a page without changing modified by property
I would like to use PnP PowerShell to make a change to multiple SharePoint Online News Post pages.  I can successfully make the change and then publish the page again using $pageName.File.Publish(), and then Invoke-PnPQuery. However this updates the modified by property to who executes the script, which I don't want as I would like to retain the original modifier.
I can use Set-PnPListItem to set the modified by field back to the original modifier, but then the page is then in draft status again.  Obviously publishing then updates the modified by field again.
So is there anyway to either:

Publish a page without updating the modified by field? e.g. a SystemUpdate  OR
Update the page properties without the need to re-publish the page


It sounds like you are trying to change a SharePoint page without anyone being able to know that it is you. Is that what you are seeking?

I don't think it's possible that SharePoint saves modified by property would be used in version control or site reports. This is designed by SharePoint.

It's to programmatically add a webpart to multiple pages using PnP PowerShell.  I would like to keep the original modified by field as it is as it is useful to see which business user last updated the page.  If all pages get updated with 'modified by' to a system account we lose this business context.
